# Using Insert, Select and values in php

Tags: php, mysql

hi i'm having difficulty trying to insert multiple row of data where userid = deviceid (Which will be taken from the .php URL)

e.g. url.com/test/this.php?deviceid=abc

This are my code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO notif (message,userid) VALUES ('hi', (select userid from devices where deviceid = '" . $deviceid . "'))";

 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

The main goal is that i want the database to insert the amount of users with the message of 'hi' as well

Here's an example

Message |  userid

hi  |  john

hi | mary

hi | Jake

etc..

please help me.. i'll do my best to reply

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO notif (message,userid)
  SELECT 'Hi', user_id 
  FROM devices WHERE
   deviceid = :deviceid
```